# How to print date in format like November 28, 2022 date and current time with AM/PM in Java

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

Kindly suggest how to WAP in Java to print date in format like- November 28, 2022 date and continuation with current time with AM/PM.

Tried below:

```
Date date = new Date(); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); 
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date); 
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output is- `28-11-2022 11:45:43 AM`, but want in format like `November 28, 2022 11:45:43 AM`.

Comment: Have a look at the Javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies, referred and able to do now by below:

Date date = new Date(); SimpleDateFormat sdf = new
    //SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date); 
    System.out.println(formattedDate);

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You want to look into the documentation of [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Note that formatting most often happens the other way around compared to the old, poor and outdated classes. We tend to prefer `yourZonedDateTime.format(yourDateTimeFormatter)` (the old way works too, though).

Answer (score 1):

Never use the terribly designed legacy date-time classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

Capture the current moment with [`ZonedDateTime#now(ZoneId zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-). Generate automatically localized text with [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
ZonedDateTime 
.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) 
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG )
    .withLocale( Locale.US )
)
```

Search to learn more. All this has been covered many many times on Stack Overflow.